# SublimeText3 newline keyboard shortcut

Tags: sublimetext3, newline, line-breaks

What is the keyboard shortcut in SublimeText3 to manually enter a line break without executing the command option? In Rstudio I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. In Excel I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

I know <kbd>Enter</kbd> yields a newline but I don't want that. I want to continue wrapping on the current line - WITH - a line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through the key bindings and there isn't one. If you have a macro that will do it, you can bind a hotkey to run that macro like this:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line.sublime-macro"} }
```

Just go to Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Key Bindings and add your new one.

[image]